# spring boot actuator works in local but not in production (aws)

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot actuator works fine on my local and I can access it in browser

```
http://localhost:8000/actuator
```

I can access my system in production as follows

```
https://somedomain.com/#/overview
```

But I cannot access the actuator when the system is deployed in AWS, when accessed as follows

```
 https://somedomain.com:8000/actuator
```

In AWS EC2 console, I notice that port 8000 is enabled as custom TCP for inbound rules

Comment: You're running this on a single EC2 instance with no load balancer?  Do you see that port 8000 is open for all incoming IP addresses?  I'd suggest that you take a small screenshot of the definition of the Security Group rule (I assume that's what you're talking about) that opens up port 8000 and show us that.  If your main HTTP(S) entrypoint is working but 8000 is not, that's the most likely spot for a problem.

Comment: ...another valuable thing you can do is ssh into the instance and try accessing "localhost:8000" from inside the instance. - You should triple-check your configuration to make sure that you didn't somehow deploy your app with a different configuration when you deployed it to AWS.  One thing I've done in the past is add few lines of code to my app to grab a Spring configuration value and log it so I can see what it is.  In this case, you'd probably want to grab the value that configures the port on which actuator is running to make sure that's 8000.

Comment: Your problem should be in AWS configurations, not in spring-boot / actuator. So I suggest you editing the question tags